# Should static methods be separated from Classes with instance methods?

Tags: java, oop, static, design-principles

As a general convention, should static method(s) be separated into another class from a class with instance methods?

Is there also an example of your reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no general convention that dictates that a static method must be separate from a non-static method.  In fact, if the two methods are related enough to one another, it would be counter-intuitive to have the methods separated.

Recall what use case static methods (and fields) have:  they're methods/fields that can be used without an instance of a particular class.  This generally means that they hold valuable metadata or perform a useful operation that's related to their class instance, but would not require direct instantiation of that class.

Take, for example, [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).  It has the static [`final`] fields `MAX_VALUE` and `MIN_VALUE`.  Since both of these fields contain fixed information that would not change between instantiations, it would not make sense to have to instantiate an `Integer` to get this information.

`Integer` also has the useful operation `parseInt`, which takes a `String` and turns it into an `int`.  We shouldn't require an instance of `Integer` to convert from `String` to `int`, *especially* if we're not placing it into an instance of `Integer`.

The overarching convention has been to **keep related methods together**, regardless of if they're static or not.  You can see clearer examples of this in certain Java library classes, like `Integer`.

Comment: Just wondering on your point there, why would you not want to create an instance of a Int to convert the string to an int?

Comment: You don't have an instance of an `Integer` to work with.  The idea is that this is a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), or something that can continually produce `int` values.

Comment: couldnt something like IntegerStatic.parseInt() work without having to create an int though? (im not trying to make out this exists just a possible idea to hopefully show my confusion)

Comment: I think the bigger confusion here is the difference between `int` and `Integer` in this example; they're *not* the same thing. In the scenario you mention, the only place it'd make practical sense to not use a static method and create a new instance of an `Integer` is via the object constructor.

Comment: sorry i meant Integer

Answer (score 2):

It probably is a duplicate question, but no, static methods have very specific benefits that are often valuable in classes that are instantiated as objects.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such convention. It's completely depends on your situation. Some class may really needs mixture of both static and non-static members.

But some times it's is seen the use of `Constatns.java/ Utils.java` class in some java project. You may found -

```
public static final double PI = 3.1416;
public static getArea(double r){}
```

This class contains some final static property and some final method. The purpose of these class to provide some constants or utility method all over the project.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely answer would be dictated by the use case but there is no convention as such. At most you have some `Utility` class that may have bunch of static methods that are used by other classes as helper methods. For example to test whether a String is an email or to extract username from email etc.

Answer (score 2):

Putting all static methods in a separate class would be useful while writing an API or a framework. [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class is an example. java.lang.Math or java.lang.System is another.

Normally, define static methods in the following scenarios:

- While writing utility classes .
- If the method does not use any instance variable.
- If any operation is in-dependent of instance creation.
- If you are sure that the definition of the method will never be changed or overridden. As static methods can not be overridden.

see here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5313383/760393